# Hover and show administration buttons

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I have, in my mind, a huge question. Or just problems with understanding hover function. I tried many methods, read lots of tutorials, but didn't get the thing, what do I need. This may be stupid, but I'm making front-end administration panel with jQuery with low knowlegde skills.

As you can see in [this image](http://i1037.photobucket.com/albums/a452/operaatoors/plain_list.jpg), this is a plain eshop list. I want to make that, if you are an admin, when you hover an item, then you can see administration buttons, like in [this image](http://i1037.photobucket.com/albums/a452/operaatoors/hovered_item.jpg), BUT only on the hovered item. Please help me get this through easy.

Anyway, here is my code for this part of the page:

```
<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".admin_item").hide();
  $('.item').hover(function() {
    $(".admin_item").slideToggle(".admin_item");
  });
});
</script>

<!-- $admin_item -->
<?
  $admin_item = '<div class="admin_item" style="position: absolute; padding-left: 380px;"><a href="?edit"><img src="style/icon/pencil.png" alt="" /></a><a href="?delete"><img src="style/icon/delete.png" alt="" /></a></div><div class="clear"></div>';
?>

<!-- list -->
<div class="page_content" id="goods">
  <?
    $items = array (
      1 => array("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.","3.65","List 3-1"),
      2 => array("Proin ut est ut purus venenatis suscipit tristique id mi.","4.00","List 3-2"),
      3 => array("Integer posuere mauris dapibus massa malesuada id malesuada velit congue.","5.49","List 3-3"),
      4 => array("Vivamus eu purus quam, ut convallis urna.","7.40","List 3-2"),
      5 => array("Suspendisse eu felis erat, ut mollis erat.","8.20","List 3-1"),
      6 => array("Morbi malesuada facilisis neque, at dapibus nibh elementum quis.","9.85","List 3-1"),
      7 => array("Proin euismod mauris ac lorem sodales faucibus.","10.00","List 3-2"),
      8 => array("Maecenas vitae neque ac nibh venenatis laoreet nec sed nisi.","12.90","List 3-3"),
    );
    $i=1;
    foreach($items as $item) :
  ?>
  <?=$admin_item?>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="details floatleft">
      <div class="image floatleft"><img src="images/items/example/thumbs/<?=$i?>_s.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="description floatleft"><?=$item[0]?></div>
      <div class="price floatleft">LVL <?=$item[1]?></div>
      <div class="category floatleft"><?=$item[2]?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart floatleft"><img src="style/shopping_cart.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <? $i++; endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're doing your slide toggle like this:

```
$(".admin_item").slideToggle(".admin_item");
```

It should be: `$(".admin_item").slideToggle([ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ]);`

Try this instead: `$(".admin_item").slideToggle('fast');`

Comment: Yeah, actually, this is right, what you are saying about durations etc. but I wish that this would worked...

Answer (score 1):

Well,  I'm assuming you are using session variables to hold your user information.  You should probably edit your post to include that information, as it is very pertinent.

So, when a user logs in, set a session variable `$_SESSION['permit'] = "admin";`, or sometimes it is easier to use numerical privilege levels : `$_SESSION['permit'] = 100;`.

Now, when you load this PHP grab that session variable and put it local : `$permit = $_SESSION['permit'];` and on your loop for creating the sale items have an if statement like this where you would like the admin panel to appear:

```
if($permit > 10) {
echo "<div class='admin_item' style='position: absolute; padding-left: 380px;'><a href='?edit'><img src='style/icon/pencil.png' alt='' /></a><a href='?delete'><img src='style/icon/delete.png' alt='' /></a></div><div class='clear'></div>";
}
```

Now in your jquery put this:

```
$("div.item").hover(function() {
     $("div.admin_item").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**  Sorry, you edited your post while I was writing my response.  Your actual jquery error is that you are writing your slideToggle function wrong.  The syntax is like this:
$("object").slideToggle(duration);

View the docs at http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Thanks for answer :) Don't worry, I haven't forget about safety :) there it is: if($rights > 2){ /// } :) 
Anyway, this didn't helped solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! :)

easy as this:

```
            $("div.admin_item").hide();
              $("div.item").hover(function() {
                $(this).find("div.admin_item").fadeIn(500);
              },function(){
                $(this).find("div.admin_item").fadeOut(500);
            });
```

Thanks guys for support!